# using self in python @patch decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'm trying to use python's mock.patch to implement unit tests with nose.

```
class A:

    def setUp(self):
        self.b = 8 #contrived example

    @patch.object('module.class', 'function', lambda x: self.b)
    def testOne(self):
        # do test #
```

Here, patch complains that it doesnt know self (which is correct). What is best way to get this kind of functionality in a clean fashion?

I know I can use a global variable, or that I can mock it within the test (but that involves me cleaning up the objects at the end of the test).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use `self` on method decorator because you are in the class definition and the object doesn't exist. If you really want to access to `self` and not just use some static values you can consider follow approach: `totest` is a module in my python path and `fn` is the method that I would patch, moreover I'm using a fixed `return_value` instead a function for a more readable example

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.b = 8 #contrived example

    def testOne(self):
        with patch('totest.fn', return_value=self.b) as m:
            self.assertEqual(self.b, m())
            self.assertTrue(m.called)

    @patch("totest.fn")
    def testTwo(self,m):
        m.return_value = self.b
        self.assertEqual(self.b, m())
        self.assertTrue(m.called)
```

In `testOne()` I use `patch` as a context and I will have the full access to `self`. In `testTwo()` (that is my standard way) I set up my mock `m` at the start of the test and then use it.

Finally I used `patch()` instead of `patch.object()` because I don't really understand why you need `patch.object()` but you can change it as you like.

Comment: testTwo looks good. There was no specific reason for using patch.object over patch. i guess this is the best way around this. Thanks!